# How to close one FORM from another FORM in C# Winform Application

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I'm working on C# winform application, in that I want to close one form from the another form i.e. I have 2 forms Form1 and Form2 and I want to close Form2 from Form1 for that I have written following code on button click event of Form1, but I'm getting the following exception-

> *"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."*

```
private void button_click(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
     Form2.ActiveForm.Disposed+= new EventHandler(closeForm2) // Getting Exception to ***closeForm2***
}

private void closeForm2(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
      Form2.ActiveForm.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 4):

For future readers!

You can use the following code to close one FORM from another FORM in C# Winform Application.

```
FrmToBeClosed obj = (FrmToBeClosed)Application.OpenForms["FrmToBeClosed"];
obj.Close();
```

Those 2 lines of code are self-explanatory!

That's it!

Comment: Or you can just `Application.OpenForms["FrmToBeClosed"].Close();`

Answer (score 0):

ActiveForm returns "Currently active form from this application" = Form you clicked...
How you start your Form2?
I think you should define it like

```
Form2 DetailsForm = null;
public void prepareForm2() //bind this to action to open new form
{
    if (DetailsForm == null)
    {
        DetailsForm = new Form2(this);
    }
}
```

Than you can just call close()/Dispose/Hide
by calling

```
private void closeForm2(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
   DetailsForm.Close();
   // or DetailsForm.Hide();
   // or DetailsForm.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I have taken a MDIParent Form and calling Form1 and Form2 on ToolStripMenuItem_Click event as shown below--   private void form1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            f.MdiParent = this;
            f.Show();
        }

        private void form2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            Form2 f = new Form2();
            f.MdiParent = this;
            f.Show();
        }

Answer (score 0):

See MSDN -> Form.ActiveForm Property

> If your application is a **multiple-document interface (MDI) application**, use the **ActiveMdiChild property** to obtain the currently active MDI child form.

I think you need a void in your MDI-Form  like

```
public void closeChild(Type FormType)
{
  foreach(Form form in this.MdiChildren)
  {
    if(typeof(form) == FormType)
    {
       /* what ever you wanna do */
    }
  }
}
```

Hope I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 CloseProgramForm closepf = new CloseProgramForm();
            closepf.ShowDialog();
            if (closeoption == 1)
                e.Cancel = false;
            else
                e.Cancel = true;
```